# Linux scripting: Search a specific column for a keyword

Tags: linux, search, awk, grep

I have a large text file that contains multiple columns of data. I'm trying to write a script that accepts a column number and keyword from the command line and searches for any hits before displaying the entire row of any matches.

I've been trying something along the lines of:

`grep $fileName | awk '{if ($'$columnNumber' == '$searchTerm') print $0;}'`

But this doesn't work at all. Am I on the right lines? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -v option can be used to pass shell variables to `awk` command.

The following may be what you're looking for:

`awk -v s=$SEARCH -v c=$COLUMN '$c == s { print $0 }' file.txt`

**EDIT:**

I am always trying to write more elegant and tighter code. So here's what Dennis means:

`awk -v s="$search" -v c="$column" '$c == s { print $0 }' file.txt`

Comment: @user1136076: I recommend quoting those shell variables.

Comment: Also, `COLUMNS` (plural) is an environment variable and a very similar name to your `COLUMN` variable. I recommend that you use lower case or mixed case variable names by habit to reduce the chance of name collision.

Comment: Note that "print $0" is redundant.  You can simply do awk ... '$c == s' file.txt

Comment: I have a function that searches one column for one string, how would I allow it so I can provide my script with multiple columns to search with multiple search strings?

    awk -v s=$1 -v c=$2 '$c ~ s { print $0 }' $3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks reasonable enough.  Try using `set -x` to look at exactly what's being passed to `awk`.  You can also use different and/or more awk things, including getting rid of the separate grep:

```
awk -v colnum=$columnNumber -v require="$searchTerm"
    "/$fileName/ { if (\$colnum == require) print }"
```

which works by setting awk variables (`colnum` and `require`, in this case) and then using the literal string `$colnum` to get the desired field, and the variable `require` to get the required-string.

Note that in all cases (with or without the `grep` command), any regular expression meta-characters in `$fileName` will be meta-y, e.g., `this.that` will match the file named `this.that` but also the file named `thisXthat`.

Comment: You're using both `-v` variable passing and embedded shell variables. I recommend that you only use variable passing, use single quotes for the outer set and avoid distracting escapes. You should also quote *all* shell variables when you use `-v`. You will need to use the match operator instead of slashes when you're matching a variable. Here is a revised version of your answer: `awk -v colnum="$columnNumber" -v require="$searchTerm" -v file="$fileName" '$0 ~ file && $colnum == require'`. Note that `print` is implied.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Yes, I was a bit lazy about the column number quoting since it has to be a number in the first place.  Note that '$0 ~ var' does not work in old awk, though, e.g., SunOS: `$ awk '$0 ~ "pattern"'` gives: `awk: syntax error near line 1`.  If you don't have to deal with ancient awk, do use the all-variable version.